# How to update a UWP app in Microsoft Store after it is migrated to WinUI?

Tags: uwp, winui-3, microsoft-store

I have migrated an app from UWP to WinUI 3 and Visual Studio no longer generates the .appxupload file. It generates a .msix file. Microsoft Partner Center does not allow the submission of myapp_x64.msix because

> "A previous submission for this app was released with a Windows 10/11
> .msixbundle or .appxbundle. Subsequent submissions must continue to
> contain a Windows 10/11 .msixbundle or .appxbundle."

It seems that I need to use MakeAppx.exe to create the bundle for submission.

I tried to use [MakeAppx.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/create-app-package-with-makeappx-tool) to create a bundle from the folder created by VS's package creation process: "...\bin\x64\Release\net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0\win-x64\AppPackages\Foo.Windows_6.0.17.0_x64_Test" and Got the following:

```
MakeAppx : error: Bundle creation failed.
MakeAppx : error: 0x8051100f - The specified package format is not valid: The zip archive is missing the end of central directory marker.
```

Could anyone share a successful experience of following migration?

- You had a UWP app in the Microsoft Store
- Migrated this app to WinUI
- Updated the package in the store successfully after the migration

Comment: you need to build an msixupload package like you created an appxupload package before. I'm not familiar with the command-line here, but in VS go to Project/Publish/create app package. Select the MSFT store in next window.

Comment: As I wrote in my question - "Visual Studio no longer generates the .appxupload file" with the normal publishing process (i.e., Project/Publish/create app package...).